# what is the correct closing order for java thread socket i/o join?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, io

i have a pipe class which may or may not have it's own thread and which may or may not have a socket, but which always has a buffered reader or a writer (usually both)

what is the correct order to shut one end of this pipe/socket down?

how about both ends of this pipe/socket when testing on local host?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Close the outermost output stream or `Writer` that you've wrapped around the socket output stream. Close the socket/pipe itself in a finally block.

Don't bother with the input stream, and don't write a redundant `flush()` before the `close().`

Same applies to both ends.

Comment: so if it has a socket, i should not try to do a shutdownInput or shutdownOutput?

Comment: @RayTayek Not unless you protocol calls for reading data after you shutdown for output, which is extremely rare.